# CSS does not take effects and it doesn't show in inspect

Tags: css, headers

Hi I am trying to do a simple thing for my header at https://blog.madesoma.com/, but I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #473C93; 
}

#branding-logo {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: auto; 
}
```

and here is my header.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Rumah_Digital
 */

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'rumah-digital' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <div class="site-branding" id="branding">
            <img src="https://blog.madesoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/icon-2088906_1280.png" id="branding-logo"> </img>

            <?php
            the_custom_logo();
            if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) :
                ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <?php
            else :
                ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
                <?php
            endif;
            $rumah_digital_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
            if ( $rumah_digital_description || is_customize_preview() ) :
                ?>
                <p class="site-description"><?php echo $rumah_digital_description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'rumah-digital' ); ?></button>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
            ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

Comment: this is a wall of code, not an actual question :(, or at least it is not clear what the question is.

Comment: Where are you even putting this CSS?

Answer (score 1):

This is the relevant section of CSS in your stylesheet:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Uling dini ke beten, Bapak Ngelah olah2an. Kangguang deen malu! 
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Header 
--------------------------------------------------------------*

.site-header {
    background-color: #473C93; 
}

#branding-logo {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: auto; 
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

If you look closely you'll see that the [CSS comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments) has not been closed properly:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------*
```

So your CSS is being interpreted as a comment. Make sure you properly close comments with `*/`.

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Header 
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Also, use an editor that has syntax highlighting. The issue would have been obvious were it enabled.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Jacob. I did play with it, but it still doesn't seem to work.

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Header 
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#masthead {
 background-color: #473C93; 
}

#branding-logo img {
float: left!important;
width: 50px !important;
height: auto !important;
}

I have a Sass folder in my file. Do you think that's the cause? Should I get rid of it?

Comment: You're still using the incorrect changes to the CSS from the other answers. Use the original CSS from your question.

Comment: Hi Jacob,
Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. I already comment my CSS correctly based on your suggestion. This is WordPress's CSS filesheet so it's already connected to the HTML. I tried to edit other elements in in the same file and they worked. Sorry if this sounds silly. I am a complete beginner.

Comment: The CSS is incorrect. In your comment you're using `#branding-logo img`, but the correct value is what you had originally: `#branding-logo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `img` to your css.

**Example:**

```
#branding-logo img {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: auto; 
}
```

**Tip:** Only use ID's on elemets that will be unique. Use Classes for styles that you want to reuse on other elements.

Currently, your image CSS has this CSS applied to it, which is making it super big.

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. I don't know if this is something that is more unique here than on other sites, but we try to have only authoritative answers, and you can not be authoritative with your answer if you are not sure what the question actually is. In case of doubt it is better in general to first ask the OP in the comments what exactly he means to make sure the answer is going to be relevant.

Answer (score -1):

In your style.css file, you should have:

```
.site-header { background-color: #473C93; }
#branding-logo { float: left; width: 50px; height: auto; }
```

**Tip:** it's always better to use ids ( when available ), to identify elements. Use:

```
#masthead { background-color: #473C93; }
#branding-logo { float: left; width: 50px; height: auto; }
```

If you don't see desired effect, it means that style.css had been read from cache. In that case, you have to hard reload your page.

Comment: lets stop answering off topic questions? It is even a bad answer as if he is not using cache busting his problem is in totally different area

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Frank. I did play with it, but it still doesn't seem to work.

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Header 
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#masthead {
 background-color: #473C93; 
}

#branding-logo img {
float: left!important;
width: 50px !important;
height: auto !important;
}

I have a Sass folder in my file. Do you think that's the cause? Should I get rid of it?